# Accidental flagging/closing issue/bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

On the latest iOS app version, the "flag" link for comments and "close" link for questions are right where I swipe up the page so I frequently hit them without intending to which leads to "why are you flagging as objectionable ?" Or "voting to close". Of course I just cancel, but it is unpleasant.

I did not have that happen before . Certainly there are some noble souls always on the hunt for bad posts. I appreciate them! For me it is like being required to carry a pistol I very seldom use, with a bullet in the chamber, a hair trigger, and no safety.

I suggest a safety for use by thick thumbed users at those times they are in a mood to just consume and contribute new content.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct – these toolbar buttons were "swallowing" the scroll touches as their own.

Swiping on the question/answer now won't accidentally trigger any of the toolbar buttons.

This will take effect in the next beta build, version 1.2.1.168.