# UI freezes randomly in iOS app 1.2.1

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, performance

I just upgraded to iOS app 1.2.1. While I like the feature enhancements, I find that it is unusable.

On a couple of occasions, an action such as upvoting raised a dialog box saying that the network was unavailable, on which I had to click <kbd>Retry</kbd> — and then it succeeded. I doubt that there was a problem with my local network at the time of these errors.

The showstopper, though, is that the UI often becomes completely unresponsive while viewing the Feed: neither tapping nor scrolling does anything. At that point, I can either kill the app or wait a *long* time and hope that it recovers.

I'm using iOS 8.1.1 on an iPhone 5S.

Comment: That's terrible. I haven't seen anything like it.  Can you tell me a little about when this starts happening? Is it random or is there a pattern?  When you say you have to wait a long time does this mean that the feed eventually does unlock and become usable (if it takes about 30 seconds that's very interesting)? Are you seeing hot questions at the top of the feed?

Comment: @BrianNickel haven't observed the super-long freezes lately. However, I do occasionally see network Retry dialog boxes. There are also short freezes while scrolling through a question and its answers, sometimes causing a gesture that was obviously intended to be a scrolling flick to be interpreted as a tap on a button.

Comment: By the way, these "scroll misinterpreted as a tap" issues  on the question were addressed here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243907/accidental-flagging-closing-issue-bug/244137#244137

Comment: [I believe I've fixed the issue that was causing the freed to freeze up.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270802/ios-app-crashes-on-startup-under-slow-internet-connections)

Comment: @BrianNickel I haven't observed any freezing for a while. If you post any answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to the specifics of why the network request were failing but I've recently switched everything over to `NSURLSession` which may help.  As far as freezing in the feed, [I've removed some blocking calls to the site store which I believe were causing it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270802/ios-app-crashes-on-startup-under-slow-internet-connections).